# Help to solve this ODE with integration and exponential function

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

So I have this system of ODEs and the unknowns are $\lambda_1(t)$ and $\lambda_2(t)$. Other parameters and functions are all known.

$\lambda_1(t)=u_{11}p_{11}e^{-u_{11}t}\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_1(x)e^{u_{11}x}dx+u_{21}p_{21}e^{-u_{21}t}\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_2(x)e^{u_{21}x}dx+g_1(t)$

$\lambda_2(t)=u_{12}p_{12}e^{-u_{12}t}\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_1(x)e^{u_{12}x}dx+u_{22}p_{22}e^{-u_{22}t}\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_2(x)e^{u_{22}x}dx+g_2(t)$

I have tried to define the integration as a function, i.e., $f_1(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_1(x)e^{u_{11}x}dx$, and then take a derivative, getting, $\lambda_1(t)=e^{-u_{11}t}f_1(t)'$. But notice that for each integration the rate of the exponential component is different. Therefore, I will have to define four different $f_i(t)$s and I have only two equations.

Any help and suggestions are much appreciated.

PS: $p$ and $u$ are all constant. The only thing unknown are the $\lambda(t) $s

Comment: Are $p$ and $u$ constant ?

Comment: Yes they are @Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lambda_1(t) =u_{11}p_{11}e^{-u_{11}t}\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_1(x)e^{u_{11}x}dx+u_{21}p_{21}e^{-u_{21}t}\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_2(x)e^{u_{21}x}dx+g_1(t)$

$\lambda_2(t)=u_{12}p_{12}e^{-u_{12}t}\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_1(x)e^{u_{12}x}dx+u_{22}p_{22}e^{-u_{22}t}\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_2(x)e^{u_{22}x}dx+g_2(t)$

$f_{11}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_1(x)e^{u_{11}x}dx$

$f_{21}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_2(x)e^{u_{21}x}dx$

$f_{12}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_1(x)e^{u_{12}x}dx$

$f_{22}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_2(x)e^{u_{22}x}dx$

Then you have a system of four linear ODEs with four unknown $\:f_{11}(t)\:$ , $\:f_{12}(t)\:$ , $\:f_{21}(t)\:$ and $\:f_{22}(t)\:$

$\lambda_1(t)=e^{-u_{11}t}f_{11}(t)'=e^{-u_{12}t}f_{12}(t)'=u_{11}p_{11}e^{-u_{11}t}f_{11}(t)+u_{21}p_{21}e^{-u_{21}t}f_{21}(t)+g_1(t)$

$\lambda_2(t)=e^{-u_{21}t}f_{21}(t)'=e^{-u_{22}t}f_{22}(t)'=u_{12}p_{12}e^{-u_{12}t}f_{12}(t)+u_{22}p_{22}e^{-u_{22}t}f_{22}(t)+g_2(t)$

[image]

Comment: Some coefficients might be incorrect but I get the idea.

Comment: OK. Possibly, they are some typo. The typing of the equations was not easy. All the best to check it.